# Reverse String Method type mismatch error java

Tags: java, string, methods, types

I am trying to use a method to reverse the characters in a string and I keep getting a type mismatch error.  Any thoughts?

```
public static String userReverse (String userEntry3) {
    String reverse = "";    
       for (int i = (userEntry3.length() -1); i >= 0 ; i--) {
       reverse = System.out.println(userEntry3.charAt(i));
    }
    return reverse;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` is a void method. It returns nothing. So it cannot assigned back to a `String` variable

Your code is wrong.

If you want to reverse a string, you can use this:

```
public static String userReverse (String userEntry3) {
    return new StringBuilder(userEntry3).reverse().toString()
}
```

Comment: Of course in practice we would do this, but maybe the OP needs to implement his own reversing logic.

Comment: Wow. `StringBuilder::reverse` had no idea this method existed before now :P

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `System.out.println` and add a `+=` to concatenate the new char

```
public static String userReverse (String userEntry3) {
    String reverse = "";    
    for (int i = (userEntry3.length() -1); i >= 0 ; i--) {
        reverse += userEntry3.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

EDIT: As Tim said in the comments, `StringBuilder` can be used too (and is better practice than concatenating strings in a loop):

```
public static String userReverse (String userEntry3) {
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();    
    for (int i = (userEntry3.length() -1); i >= 0 ; i--) {
        reverse.append(userEntry3.charAt(i));
    }
    return reverse.toString();
}
```

Comment: Still there is no explanation, why `StringBuilder` is better and what is wrong with `System.out.println()` Poor programming(er) instance.

Answer (score 0):

A more optimized way to reverse a string includes two pointer approach:
Use one pointer to start from the beginning and the other to start from the end. By the time they meet each other your string is already reversed

```
public static String userReverse (String userEntry3) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = userEntry3.length()-1;
    StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(userEntry3);

    for(; i < j ; i++,j--){
        char temp = userEntry3.charAt(i);
        myName.setCharAt(i,userEntry3.charAt(j));
        myName.setCharAt(j,temp);
    }
    return myName.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println() is a void method and it not return anything. you should try it this way,

```
public static String userReverse (String userEntry3) {
String reverse = "";    
  for (int i = (userEntry3.length() -1); i >= 0 ; i--) {
   reverse += userEntry3.charAt(i).toString();
}
return reverse;
}
```

Comment: Of course, This is a simplest thing to do in this situation.